# Python post array of string

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, vmware

I have issues doing post requests of JSON array of strings to vmware rest api. Would appreciate if somebody have a look at it.

```
def request_post(vcip):
    session = requests.Session()
    session.verify = False
    session1 = session.post('https://'+vcip+'/rest/com/vmware/cis/session', auth=('******', '*******'), verify=False)
    session_id = session1.json()["value"]
    return session_id

def request_get(vcip, cmd, session_id):
    session = requests.Session()
    session.verify = False
    result = session.get('https://'+vcip+''+cmd+'', verify=False, headers={"vmware-api-session-id": session_id})
    return result.json()

def check_if_my_tag_or_not(vcip, tag, s):
    my_category_id = 'urn:vmomi:InventoryServiceCategory:xxxxxxxxxxf1-b8a2-946c84d7ed90:GLOBE'
    result = request_get(vcip, '/rest/com/vmware/cis/tagging/tag/id:'+tag+'', s)
    if result['value']['category_id'] == bkp_category_id:
       return result

def request_post1(vcip, cmd, s, tags):
    payload = [{"tag_ids": tags}]
    session = requests.Session()
    session.verify = False
    tags = json.dumps(payload)
    print(tags)
    session1 = session.post('https://'+vcip+''+cmd+'',headers={'vmware-api-session-id':s, 'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json'}, verify=False, data=tags)
    print(session1.content)
    return session1.json()

def main():

    vcip = '*************'
    s = request_post(vcip)
    tags = []
    tag = request_get(vcip, '/rest/com/vmware/cis/tagging/tag', s)
    for tag in tag['value']:
        result = check_if_my_tag_or_not(vcip, tag, s)
        if result is not None:
           tag = result['value']
           tag_id = tag['id']
           tags.append(tag_id)
    vm_with_bkp_tag = request_post1(vcip, '/api/cis/tagging/tag-association?action=list-attached-objects-on-tags', s, tags)
    print(vm_with_bkp_tag)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

```
tags = [{"tag_ids": ["urn:vmomi:InventoryServiceTag:8fb2044e-fea1-4456-ad79-d0026f246328:GLOBE","urn:vmomi:InventoryServiceTag:aeafb8e0-56d6-4a47-bf1d-9e10453b2d0e:GLOBE", "urn:vmomi:InventoryServiceTag:3d33f253-f1c2-4666-b5e9-0c3a6fb25258:GLOBE"]}]
```

On VMware document, https://developer.vmware.com/docs/vsphere-automation/latest/cis/api/cis/tagging/tag-associationactionlist-attached-objects-on-tags/post/
It's mentioned that request body must be "array of string".

The error:

```
b'{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":null,"error":{"code":-32600,"message":"Invalid Request","data":"Received unexpected json token START_OBJECT"}}'
{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': None, 'error': {'code': -32600, 'message': 'Invalid Request', 'data': 'Received unexpected json token START_OBJECT'}}
```

At this stage I am without options, and I'm not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

It worked, I was missing the:

```
vm_with_bkp_tag = request_post1(vcip, '/api/cis/tagging/tag-association?action=**~**list-attached-objects-on-tags', s, tags)
```